# How to open a Visualforce Page in a tab into the Service Console lightning

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, console

How can I open a **Visualforce** Page in a tab into the **Service Console lightning**?

I tried with the  **workspaceAPI** `openSubTab()` method, but the documentation says that Visualforce is not supported as URL parameter.

I also tried launching a `force:navigateToUrl` event in the openSubTab callback, but it opens the page in the current tab.

Is there any way to open it in a new tab?

Comment: Which document indicates you can't use Visualforce as a parameter in openSubtab? In the "URL" parameter you should be able to simply use a relative URL value like "/apex/myVFPage" if you want to open a VF page.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_lightning_opentab.htm

Say "Visualforce page are not supported"

Comment: Ah, sorry. I was looking at the classic API and not the Lightning one. I am not sure if there is another way to do it if the API doesn't support it yet.

Comment: Depending on how good of a fit it is to your requirements, you could use the VF page as a component in a lightning page and open that flexipage in the console. https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/projects/workshop-lightning-programmatic/steps/programmatic-step-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try api 42, as per release notes the disclaimer regarding Visualforce pages has been removed: now you can even open other domain urls via CSP.